# How to start the default browser (and/or any default application) from command line on Solaris?

Tags: command-line, solaris, browser

I'd like to open a URL in the default internet browser from my application. My application gets compiled for MS-Windows, Linux, Mac and Solaris.

One way to achieve that on Windows is using the shell command `start`, on Linux using the `xdg-open`, on Mac there is `open`. As a bonus, all these commands can also open any file in their default applications.

However I can't find any similar reliable command (or API) on Solaris.

I've heard about `sdtwebclient` but since it is not on my machine running Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10), it seems not to be safe to assume that it is usually there.

Any suggestions how to launch the default browser in a (more or less) reliable way on any Solaris machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sdtwebclient` will be installed under `/usr/dt/bin` if CDE is installed, which limits it to Solaris 10 and older machines.

For Solaris 11 and later, use `xdg-open` just as you would on Linux.

Comment: sdtwebclient was in fact at /usr/dt/bin. I was expecting it in the PATH like xdg-open usually is. I have also checked a Solaris 11 machine and you are right: There is xdg-open, but /usr/dt/bin/sdtwebclient is missing. I can work with that. Thanks a lot!